# Что если код - не код?

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, локализация

Некоторое время назад обратил внимание на странное уведомление:

> код в ответе исправлен
>   ["Hello, World!"](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/56018/revisions)

Речь идёт о ревизии 2, в которой сделано несколько стилистических исправлений, никак не затрагивающих код. Так почему же "*код* в ответе исправлен"?

[image: код в ответе исправлен]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Если я верно понял](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216822/), указанная правка содержит [нетривиальные изменения](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135411/274323), то есть в котором были изменены как минимум 10 символов. Для технических сайтов, где доступно выделение кода, изменения двух и более символов считаются не тривиальными.

Comment: Неверно.. Речь о формулировке "код в ответе исправлен". Зачем слово _"код"_ в формулировке? Почему не просто "Ответ исправлен" или "сообщение исправлено"? Кстати, в английском варианте на твоём скрине написано "post edited" - никаких "code in post". UPD: Хм.. Или это я неверно понял ответ...

Comment: @Qwertiy Такая строка на Transifex лишь [одна](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263200?key=a4f359cbdd0ab84721ed633942a7eb53) и является дословным переводом. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как звучит формулировка нотификации на английском?

Comment: Хм.. Неожиданно, но _"code edited on answer"_. Тогда я не понимаю, где в той правке изменение кода. Потому что блок с кодом никто не трогал.

Comment: @Qwertiy На сколько я вижу, там есть блок `\r\n\r\n`. Возможно в нем причина.

Comment: Ого! Ясно, спасибо!