# Уведомления при правках сообщений участникам с низкой репутацией

Tags: обсуждение, правки, уведомления, несущественные-правки

В общем, когда у меня была низкая репутация (<500), после [правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/853628/revisions) одного из участников кода в моем ответе, мне не пришло уведомление о новой правке. 
И если бы я не проверил случайно этот ответ чуть позже, я бы так и не узнал об этой правке. Данная правка кардинально меняла смысл кода, который я заложил изначально в ответ, и участник не посчитал нужным написать комментарий что он внес такую-то правку (я сейчас не обвиняю этого участника, почему расскажу далее).

Совсем недавно опять было исправлено мое сообщение (участник, внесший правку, имел репутацию меньше чем у меня), но в этот раз я не просто увидел уведомление, я мог принять или отклонить эту правку (видимо поэтому участник первой правки и не написал комментарий, т.к. предположил что мне хотя бы придет уведомление).

Мне кажется не следует в этом случае сильно ограничивать права участников с низкой репутацией, и хотя бы показывать им уведомления о новых правках.

Comment: Скорее всего тут дело не в том, сколько репутации у Вас, а в том, сколько её у автора правки.

Comment: @vp_arth Когда я обратил внимание первого участника на то, что 1) правка была внесена в код и 2) он не уведомил меня об этом - он не придал этому никакого значения.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы для полноты картины приложить к вопросу ссылки на правки, о которых говорите?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/853628/218976

Comment: Вы абсолютно зря [удалили](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853607/Приложение-на-c-не-связывается-с-БД-на-другом-компьютере/853628#comment1375580_853628) свой ответ..

Comment: @vp_arth восстановил его. Сделал это (удаление ответа) под эмоциями.

Comment: Правки опытных участников не могут являться признаком неуважения - они тратят своё время, чтобы сделать Ваш ответ лучше. Спасибо!

Comment: @vp_arth Целиком с вами согласен, но если участник вносит изменения в код- мне кажется правильнее в данном случае уведомить автора кода, ибо повторюсь- если бы  не обратил внимание на изменение- я бы не знал что мой ответ изменили.

Comment: @Anamnian *"он не уведомил меня об этом"* - а вот это вранье. Первый же комментарий под вашем ответе - это и есть уведомление о правке и ее обоснование.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3336/178988 - почему-то мне кажется, что уведомление ты просто не заметил.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218976/anamnian?tab=responses&sort=revisions - тебе эта страница доступна?

Comment: Переместите, пожалуйста, зелёную галочку)

Comment: @Qwertiy действительно доступна. По всей видимости вы правы, и я действительно в пылу эмоций не заметил этого уведомления.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Если смотреть по времени, комментарий написан в 11:05, правка внесена в 11:06. Но вы утверждаете что уведомили об изменении после изменения "Первый же комментарий под вашем ответе - это и есть уведомление о правке и ее обоснование." - мне кажется это вы здесь пытаетесь ввести всех в заблуждение.

Comment: Я отдаю себе отчет, в том что вопросы и ответы на этом сайте являются коллективным достоянием. Давайте закроем дальнейшее обсуждение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уведомления о правках не приходят для правок, которые считаются несущественными:

- Изменяют только метки
- Изменяют меньше определенного количества символов в сообщении

Репутация не имеет значения.

Источник: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415/370389

**UPD:** Количество измененных символов в правке, требуемых для того, чтобы правка считалась существенной, равно 10 (2 в случае редактирования кода), согласно данному [ответу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135411/370389).

Comment: Прекрасно, осталось выяснить «определённое количество символов» для ruSO

Comment: Я бы лучше сослался на [другой ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278032/339911).

Answer (score 4):

Данный ответ немного *не о том*. Механизм уведомлений о правках существует и не зависит от репутации.
Подробнее, см [соседний ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7587/176064).

---

У нас предусмотрено 2 сценария редактирования сообщений:

- Если у участника репутация меньше 2000, он «вносит предложение правки», которое может подтвердить или отклонить либо автор(ему приходит уведомление), либо несколько других участников(из специальной очереди проверок)
- Если у участника репутация больше 2000, ресурс доверяет ему — он получает [привилегию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) исправлять любые вопросы/ответы без проверки

[Почему кто-то может редактировать мои сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

> Весь вклад в жизнь сообщества юридически регламентируется лицензией Creative Commons, и этот сайт редактируется совместно, подобно Википедии. Если вы видите, что что-то требует доработки, отредактируйте это!
>
> Редактирование необходимо для поддержания ясности, точности и актуальности контента.

Comment: Только в данной справке не говорится, что код тоже может подвергаться правке: исправление грамматических и синтаксических ошибок;
уточнение и/или объяснение сообщения (без изменения его смысла);
внесение информации, которая находится в комментариях, для обеспечения целостности сообщения;
добавление актуальной информации, ресурсов и гиперссылок, относящихся к сообщению;
исправление небольших ошибок, опечаток.

Comment: Причем даже есть отдельное уточнение: (без изменения его смысла). Мне кажется изменение кода попадает как раз под изменение смысла, поправьте меня если я не прав.

Comment: Правки бывают разные, бывают уместные и неуместные. Участники с высокой репутацией редко делают неуместные правки. Для неуместных правок предусмотрена процедура отката.

Comment: Под изменением смысла подразумевается - дать другой ответ или задать новый вопрос на месте старого. Не понимаю, зачем это может понадобиться, когда всегда можно разместить свой, но такое тоже случается

Comment: Хотя я забыл про момент с уведомлением- если правка от участника с более чем 2000 репутации- мне разве не должно было придти уведомление?

Comment: Такие участники считаются «проверенными». Уведомление вроде бы(я точно не уверен) не должно приходить. Мы с Вами можем это проверить, если желаете. =)

Comment: Уже проверено- вы внесли правку в вопрос- не было уведомления.

Comment: Если Вы желаете, чтобы подобные уведомления были, нужно делать feature-request на [meta.se] со всеми вытекающими. Шансов, что это реализуют довольно мало(механизм уведомлений - довольно прожорливая вещь - это повлечёт дополнительные расходы по железу), но они есть.

Comment: [Пример отклонённой фичи](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1752/230511) - уведомление о том, что пост, который я минусанул, изменился. Очень хочется этой фичи(чтобы снять минус с хорошего контента), но нет :(

Comment: Вопрос про уведомления о правках, а не про лицензию.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, да, мой ответ был вызван скорее духом вопроса, чем буквой. Видимо, читая вопрос, я сделал излишний акцент на `я мог принять или отклонить эту правку`. Надеюсь всё же, что этот ответ не совсем бесполезен)