# Исправление чужих ответов без проверки

Tags: обсуждение, правки, ответы

Возможность свободно и бесконтрольно править чужие ответы выглядит одной из самых сомнительных возможностей SO. Как показывает этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/935161/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA/935166?noredirect=1#comment1551917_935166), высокая репутация совершено не гарантирует следование правилам, что уж там говорить о каких-то этических нормах. Мне кажется, правильней было бы отправлять на проверку все правки, без скидок на репутацию.

UPD: Или как вариант, разобраться с уведомлениями. Автор должен хотя бы знать, что его ответ или вопрос изменили.

Comment: Разве улучшение ответа не приветствуется? Тут как-то всё двояко.

Comment: @L.F.C, правка не должна менять содержание. Если знаете лучший ответ, напишите его, а не редактируйте чужой.

Comment: А с чем именно надо разбираться в уведомлениях? Они очевидно есть, по крайней мере, на столь большие правки. Это, конечно, никак не оправдывает внесение некорректных правок.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, "_Они очевидно есть_" - кому очевидно? Мне вот совсем неочевидно, я ни разу не получал уведомлений о правках моих сообщений. Правки были, уведомлений не было.

Comment: *я ни разу не получал уведомлений о правках моих сообщений* - а кто-то их правил? Можно пример, без учета смен меток, при изменении которых оповещения не приходят. *Правка не должна менять содержание* - менять скорее всего нет, а дополнять и улучшать - да. И к примеру поменяли, ну это же единичные случаи на весь SO

Comment: Ещё момент. К примеру, если автор ответа, дает ответ используя устаревшие технологии, которые не юзают или они вот-вот умрут, такой вопрос можно менять, если знаешь более новое и оптимальное решение, или же надо просто проходить мимо?

Comment: @freim Уже обсуждалось, например, здесь: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7585/Уведомления-при-правках-сообщений-участникам-с-низкой-репутацией О незначительных правках уведомления не приходят. Могут быть и другие причины, банальный баг как на стороне сайта, так и на стороне браузера.

Comment: @L.F.C, не надо менять чужие вопросы и ответы, нужно или дать свой ответ, или проходить мимо. Неважно какие там "устаревшие технологии" использует автор, это его ответ. Тем более правка с изменением смысла запрещена правилами.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, проблема в том, что даже небольшая правка может радикально изменить смысл ответа. А даже очень большая может быть чисто косметической. Уведомления нужны для всех правок.

Comment: Одни за изменение смысла, другие против. Что-то я уже потерялся. Сколько людей - столько мнений. Просто по правилам и всё, не надо ничего выдумавать.

Comment: Дело, в том, что механизм уведомлений - самое слабое место Stack Exchange в плане надежности. Уведомления о повышении репутации и сейчас регулярно отваливаются. Если рассылать уведомления на любые правки, нагрузка на систему уведомлений сильно возрастет и все будет ломаться. Правки, меняющие 1-2 буквы, встречаются очень часто, так как людям свойственно делать опечатки.

Answer (score 6):

Правку всегда можно откатить. Есть же история версий и кнопка отката на каждой версии. Нет смысла загружать кучу народа проверками ради единичных случаев, которые легко исправляются.

Comment: Я о некоторых правках своих ответов/вопросов вообще случайно узнаю, т.к. система уведомлений на SO говёная и бывает, что не отображается в меню сверху пуш.

Comment: @Suvitruf если только метки меняются, то уведомлений нет.

Comment: @älёxölüt да текст тоже иногда. Вижу только в странице профиля, там на вкладке "реакции".

Comment: Отвечающие не всегда знают, что можно откатить. Или не всегда отслеживают правки. Или вообще не понимают систему правок. Возможность отката нужна, но это не решение проблемы.

Comment: @freim Какой проблемы? Если проблема - отсутствие уведомлений о правках, то зачем пытаться продавить "давайте откажется от правок"? Квертий прав: подавляющее число правок улучшают вопрос, всегда можно найти пару плохих и на этом основании отказываться от проверок? Вы не представляете себе, сколько плохих правок в очереди и сколько-таки пролезают сквозь фильтр из пяти пар глаз - и что, никто же не предлагает демонтировать систему проверок.

Comment: @Suvitruf оформил [запрос в поддержку](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322744/339911)

Comment: @A K, это где я предлагал "давайте откажется от правок"? И я прекрасно представляю себе сколько мусора в очереди правок, я их тоже проверяю. Согласен, что уведомления о правках это хороший вариант решения.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в том- то и проблема, что эти, пусть и единичные случаи, совсем не "легко исправляются". Автор часто либо не знает, что их можно откатить, либо вообще не знает, что кто-то там что-то исправил.

Comment: @Suvitruf, вроде бы правки меньше 6 символов, если они не затрагивают код, не вызывают уведомлений. Хотя по числу символов могу ошибаться. Но любая правка кода, в том числе внутристрочного, уведомление вызывает.

Comment: @freim То есть как это "где я предлагал"? Вон, в вопросе: "правильней было бы отправлять на проверку все правки, без скидок на репутацию": вы именно предлагаете на основании пары сомнительных кейсов убрать всем возможность править без сбора консилиума из пяти участников. Вы могли бы предложить решать проблему уведомлений - но предложили совсем другое, поэтому я и спросил "а КАКУЮ проблему собственно решаем?"

Comment: @A K, не надо творчески трактовать мои высказывания и приписывать мне то, что я не говорил. В вопросе ясно написано о какой проблеме речь, а именно о бесконтрольных правках. Да, уведомления эту проблему тоже решат, я не подумал о такой возможности. Вопрос исправил.