# Почему при редактировании вопроса или ответа к автору не приходит уведомление?

Tags: поддержка, правки, уведомления

Проводя время на сайте SO столкнулся (как и все присутствующие) с тем, что мои вопросы и ответы редактируются другими участниками.

Вопрос такой - предположим задал я вопрос или дал ответ на чужой вопрос. Все это медленно погружается в бездну забвения на сайте SO, формируя, как тут любят говорить, "уникальную базу знаний". Но вполне можно представить, что кто-то редактирует старые вопросы и ответы (в которые уже никто не смотрит) без ведома авторов. Шизофреников в мире предостаточно, а при редактировании вопросов и ответов к их авторам не приходит никакого уведомления.

Вопрос - как на сайте SO борются с "отложенным по времени вандализмом"? И не стоит ли сделать отправку уведомления автору, если кто-то посторонний редактирует его вопрос или ответ?

Comment: Разве такие правки не попадают в очередь проверок?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Не знаю. Знаю только что когда мой вопрос или ответ правят, то мне не приходит никакого уведомления.

Comment: @iluxa1810 если у того, кто правит, много репы, то в очередь не попадает.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7585/

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Указанное вам обсуждение так и не ответило на вопрос, как же защититься от "отложенного во времени вандализма".

Comment: Это был ответ (возможный) на "Почему при редактировании вопроса или ответа к автору не приходит уведомление?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любые правки приводят к всплытию вопроса  на главной странице, а значит и к его просмотру другими участниками. Поэтому вандализм с большой вероятностью будет замечен.

Ну и не забывайте, что на этом сайте всего-то менее 700 участников с правом редактирования постов в обход очереди проверок. Это довольно небольшое число, чтобы среди них было достаточно шизофреников.

Comment: [чтобы среди них было достаточно шизофреников] Ну не скажите, не скажите. Недавно один доброхот поправил в моем вопросе букву "е" на букву "ё" в словах "еще" и "счетчик". Именно после этого я задумался о количестве шизофреников на сайте.

Comment: [Любые правки приводят к всплытию вопроса на главной странице] Что-то я не заметил, чтобы исправленные вопросы всплывали на главной, хотя об этом что-то слышал. А ведь еще можно править ответы. Разве правка ответа тоже поднимает вопрос в очереди?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Главная страница с некоторого времени показывает только то, что сайт считает для вас интересным. Так что скорее "возможному всплытию". А вот на страницу текущих вопросов всегда всплывает.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight если ещё точнее, то если вопрос в принципе виден в интересном - то при любом редактировании (хоть самого вопроса, хоть ответа к нему) он всплывёт.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 а что не так с буквой "ё" в слове "счётчик"? Писать тут эту букву, конечно же, не обязательно, но и вандализмом она точно не является.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Конечно, сама по себе замена буквы "е" на букву "ё" вандализмом не является. Но показателем некоторой неадекватности является. Очень странно на сайте, на котором каленым железом выжигают слова "здравствуйте", "спасибо", "пожалуйста", видеть замену буквы "е" на букву "ё". То-ли перфекционизм в конечной стадии, то-ли шизофрения в начальной стадии. Причем этот орел поправил букву "ё" только в моем вопросе, хотя по-идее ему надо бы весь трафик править ибо мало кто пользуется буквой "ё". В любом случае именно этот случай сподвигнул меня задать этот вопрос.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 простите, а как выжигание приветствий противоречит использованию буквы "ё"?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 что же до того почему был исправлен только ваш вопрос - тут всё просто. Заметил - исправил, не заметил - не исправил.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 и да, "перфекционизм в конечной стадии" - это вообще-то и есть дух сайта. Любое сообщение следует улучшать пока есть возможность делать это.

Comment: [выжигание приветствий] Ну как же. Выжигание приветствий тут идет под соусом "мы все тут очень деловые, давайте не тратить наше драгоценное время на написание и чтение приветствий". Ну ладно, давайте не тратить. И вдруг среди этой деловой вакханалии самых деловых кто-то правит букву "е" на букву "ё". Что является более чем необязательным, ибо в современном русском языке нет мест где нужна буква "ё". И всегда понятно, что "счетчик" это "счётчик", а "еще" это "ещё". Так что надо определяться, либо тут все деловые и экономят даже на "спасибо", либо букву "ё" вставляют.

Comment: [Любое сообщение следует улучшать] Ну что же, прекрасно. Вот в Вашем ответе перед "чтобы" должна быть запятая. Также "с большой вероятностью" должно быть выделено запятыми. И что теперь, будем везде пунктуацию править, по всей базе данных?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 вы путаете роли участников. "Деловые" одни, исправляют другие. Одно другому не мешает. Да, за "чтобы" спасибо. А вот по "с большой вероятностью" хотелось бы увидеть правило.

Answer (score 4):

Не знаю, почему вы не получаете уведомлений. Но вот я на личном опыте могу подтвердить, что уведомления о правках моих сообщений (как предложенных, так и монопольно выполняемых высокореповыми участниками) мне приходят. Для примера несколько скриншотов из [глобального инбокса](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox):

> [image: answer edited]

> [image: question edited]

> [image: edit suggested]

Есть ограничение, что в случае "мелких" правок, например, если были изменены только лишь метки, такие уведомления действительно не создаются. Но это, уже отдельный случай, не затрагивающий вашу ситуацию, если я правильно понял проблему.

Возможно, всё же имеет быть место какая-то частная настройка на ruSO, вроде бы такое возможно, если опираться на вопрос на MSE: [No notification was received for an edit to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202359/339911)